# OLS estimation of $y_{n+1}$ and $\epsilon_{n+1}$

Tags: inference, least-squares

I'm trying the solve the problem and opening this post to track my progress. **Any feedback/comments/hints will be greatly appreciated!**

updated 2/6/2021

**Problem:**

> Suppose $$y_{i}=x_{i}^{'}\beta+\epsilon_{i}, \forall i=1,...,n,n+1$$ where $E[\epsilon|x]=0$ and $$E[\epsilon\epsilon^{'}|x]=\sigma^{2}I.$$ $y_{1}, ..., y_{n}$ are observed as $x_{1}, ..., x_{n}, x_{n+1}$. Let $\hat\beta_{n}$ be the OLS estimator for the first $n$ observations. We want to predict $y_{n+1}$.

**a.**

> Define $$\hat y_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^{'}\hat\beta_{n}.$$ and let $$y_{n+1}^{*} = x_{n+1}^{'}\beta_{n}$$ be the population predictor of $y_{n+1}.$ Let $$\hat \epsilon_{n+1} = y_{n+1} - \hat y_{n+1}.$$ **Verify if $\hat y_{n+1}$ is unbiased**, ie $$E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x_{n+1}]=0$$.

**My attempt:**

$$E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x_{n+1}]= E[y_{n+1} - \hat y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}]=E[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}] - E[\hat y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}]$$

By linearity and strict exogeneity ($[\epsilon|x]=0$), we know $E[y_{i}|X]=x_{i}^{'}\beta$, thus
$$E[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}] - E[\hat y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}] = x_{n+1}^{'}\beta - x_{n+1}^{'}\hat \beta = x_{n+1}^{'}(\beta - \hat \beta).$$
Furthermore, $$E[x_{n+1}^{'}(\beta - \hat \beta)] = x_{n+1}^{'}(E[\beta] - \hat \beta).$$
Since $E[\beta] = \hat \beta$, $$E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x_{n+1}]=E[x_{n+1}^{'}(\beta - \hat \beta)]=0$$

**b.**

> Compute $Var(\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x)$.

**My attempt:**
$$Var(\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x) = E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}^{2}|x]-E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}|x]^{2} = E[\hat \epsilon_{n+1}^{2}|x] = E[(y_{n+1} - \hat y_{n+1})^{2}|x]$$
Plugging in $E[y_{i}|X]=x_{i}^{'}\beta$, $E[\epsilon\epsilon^{'}|x]=\sigma^{2}I$ and expanding the squares I get $$x^{'2}_{n+1}E[\beta^{2}|x]+\sigma^{2}I+2x^{'}_{n+1}E[\beta\epsilon_{n+1}|x]-x^{'2}_{n+1}\hat\beta^{2}$$

**QUESTIONS**:

1. How do I compute $E[\beta^{2}|x]$..?
2. Is there any property that gives us $E[\beta\epsilon_{n+1}|x]=E[\beta|x]E[\epsilon_{n+1}|x]$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi: for a) don't use LLN. just take the expectation of the prediction and see what you get.  for b) you're on the right track. Now compute the variance of ( $y_{n+1} - \hat{y}_{n+1})$.

Comment: Hi: The thing you're trying to compute for b) is surprisingly involved. It's the prediction variance. I would try to follow along since you'll learn a lot. ( atleast I did ).  if you google for "prediction variance in classical linear regression", the document is the one by shalab, titled: "chapter 2: Simple Linear Regression Analysis.".  The gory details are  on page 29. I couldn't come up with the exact link to it.